Refresh materialized views concurrently inside a transaction
I have 2 tables, a parent table and a child table.  The parent table and the child table are linked together with a foreign key.  Both the parent and child table have their own primary keys.
create table parent (
   parent_id integer primary key,
   data ... 
);
create table child(
   child_id integer primary key,
   parent_id integer references parent(parent_id),
   data ...
);

I want to make a pair of materialized views to store a copy of the data for the parent and the child table, so I make 2 materialized views.
create materialized view view_parent as select * from parent;
create unique index on view_parent(parent_id);
create materialized view view_child as select * from child;
create unique index on view_child(child_id);

Now when I decide to refresh the views the problem I foresee is if you are continually adding to the base tables depending on the order in which you refresh the materialized views you may either get child rows with no parent (if you do the parents first) or parent rows with no child (if you do the children first).  Deletions can cause similar problems between the two tables.
One way I thought may avoid this would be to do the refresh in a transaction, because at least if you do that refreshes should view the parent tables at the same stage of their development, but how much of the system would this lock up?  I would ideally like to essentially snapshot both parent tables and refresh the materailized view, allowing users to view the materialized views without locking them out, and allow writes into the parent tables, again not locking users out of them either.  Would doing the refresh materialized view in a transaction lock out either readers of the materialized view or writers to the parent tables?

Slightly offtopic, but what problem should it solve? Why do you want to implement materialized views?

I was asked to make materialized views for others to consume.  Currently the materialized views are a subset of the fields in the base tables, but as the database evolves we don't want the underlying tables to be locked into any specific form because of what the users may be doing.  For example if we had to denormalize a field that could break what materialized view consumers did.  With the views the create view statement could be edited to preserve its current form.

Sounds like premature optimization.

"you may either get child rows with no parent (if you do the parents first)" -> That would be "if you do the children first" but anyway, with the foreign key from child to parent, this is not possible, is it? The opposite goes for deletion: you cannot delete a parent without deleting its children and if you were to add ON DELETE CASCADE, you could even delete in both tables at once (You can in fact always insert or delete in 2 tables in the same query).

And regarding having parents with no children, how would it be a problem? From your description, I conclude your goal is to select data in 1 query (otherwise I don't see how being forced to refresh the views in 2 queries would be relevant to your problem), i.e. with a JOIN -> if what you plan on doing is an outer join, I expect you'd be prepared to have parents with no child and if an inner join, the parents won't be returned so everything will look as if the parents were not there. Either way I see it, I do not understand what problem you expect...

If normal views won't do for you, and you want the data duplication, you could proceed as follows:

create a new schema

create materialized views in the new schema without using CONCURRENTLY, so that you can create all materialized views in a single REPEATABLE READ transaction

at some point, kill all sessions that use the schema with the old materialized views, remove the schema and rename the new schema


The last step could work as follows:
In one session, run
SELECT pg_backend_pid();

DROP SCHEMA oldschema CASCADE;

In another session, run
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(s)
FROM unnest(pg_blocking_pids(12345));

where 12345 is the process ID found with the first statement.
As soon as the DROP SCHEMA is done (which should be soon), the first session renames the new schema:
ALTER SCHEMA newschema RENAME TO oldschema;

